# How to change font size of all text in a table?

Tags: tables, fontsize

Hi I am trying the following code but only the first row (the headings) is being changed to the specified font size. How can I make the whole table's font size change?

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\fontsize{11}{9}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm}}
\hline
\hline
\Result 1 & Result 2 & Result 3 \\ [0.2ex] 
\hline
22 & 34 & 12\\ 
\hline
65 & 43 & 55\\ 
\hline
42 & 76 & 23\\ [1ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: @MarioS.E. I tried that its still only resizing the first row

Comment: Consider using the [`booktabs` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), because it is awesome.

Comment: @Matt9Atkins as posted it will not resize the font at all. If you are seeing a change in the first row you must have a font selection there, such as `\textbf`.

Answer (score 20):

Font size settings such as `\fontsize{11}{9}`  do not take effect until `\selectfont` is issued so that should be

```
\fontsize{11}{9}\selectfont
```

But that selects an 11pt font on a 9pt baseline so the text will not fit in the allocated space and you will get irregular spaced lines. Perhaps you intended

```
\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont
```

Or better

```
\small
```

Answer (score 9):

If you have multiple tables (using tabular) in the document, to save you from some typing you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\begin{center}\small}
\AfterEndEnvironment{tabular}{\end{center}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{table}{!htbp}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
Result 1 & Result 2 & Result 3 \\
\midrule
22 & 34 & 12\\ 
65 & 43 & 55\\ 
42 & 76 & 23\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the table construction is cleaner now =).

Comment: I used this one but removed the `\begin{center}` from the `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and did no `\AfterEndEnvironment` because it was causing the tables to have a lot of padding above and below when it came to how far captions were displayed.

Answer (score 6):

Or you can juste put a `{\Large`... your table... `}` like this...

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\fontsize{11}{9}
\centering
{\Large %                                   <------ Here
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm}}
\hline
\hline
Result 1 & Result 2 & Result 3 \\ [0.2ex] 
\hline
22 & 34 & 12\\ 
\hline
65 & 43 & 55\\ 
\hline
42 & 76 & 23\\ [1ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}
}%                                          <---- And here
\end{table}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It's not very professional, but il works ;)

Comment: Why not very professional? Is there a disadvantage to using this simple method?